# LightBox v2 shrinks the image in the box

Tags: plugins, lightbox, lightbox2

I'm currently working on the small gallery site for myself and to display each image I decided to use the LightBox v2 plugin. http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

But unfortunately, it is not simple as I would like. The plugin works, I mean, I can display images in the lightbox (I have the Prev/Next button, this is not the problem) but each image is shrinked in width and I really don't understand why!

Here an example of how it is currently looks like:
http://sdz-upload.s3.amazonaws.com/prod/upload/Capture%20d%E2%80%99e%CC%81cran%202013-07-08%20a%CC%80%2011.49.56.png

And here my code:

```
<h2>Par Catégorie</h2>

<?php

$reqcategorie = db_query('SELECT * FROM photos');
    while($donneecategorie = $reqcategorie->fetch()) { 
        ?>
<a href="index.php?page=fiche&categorie=<?php echo $donneecategorie['categorie'];?>"><?php echo $donneecategorie['categorie'];?></a>

<?php

    }

?>
```

If you already used this plugin and have encountered this issue, please tell me how you solved it.

PS: I'm using Twitter Bootstrap, is there any incompatibility between both of them?

Answer (score 10):

Add the following css rule:

```
.lb-image{
  max-width: inherit;
}
```

Bootstrap has default img max-width set to 100% and for some reason lightbox stops resizing.

--
Solution emailed to me by https://github.com/kiballion. Credit where credit is due.

Comment: Had the same issue with Foundation 3. Worked like a charm - thanks!

Comment: This didn't work for me, as the container was always with a fixed width. I had no bootstrap or foundation framework loaded. I had to set the `width` of the image container `.lb-outerContainer` to auto, in order to work.